# Help in finding fourier integral representation.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-transform, integral-transforms

So i have to prove the following equality;

> $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(\pi w/2)\cos(wx)}{1-w^2}dw=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(x)&\mbox{ si }|x|\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\\0&\mbox{ si }|x|>\frac{\pi}{2}\end{array}\right.$$

So, what i have done is taking the function

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(x)&\mbox{ si }|x|\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\\0&\mbox{ si }|x|>\frac{\pi}{2}\end{array}\right.$$

By the general from of the  fourier integral, we got

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\left[A(\alpha)\cos(\alpha x)+B(\alpha)\sin(\alpha x)\right]d\alpha$$

where

$$A(\alpha)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\cos(\alpha x)dx\quad\mbox{ and }
\quad B(\alpha)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\sin(\alpha x)dx.$$

So, being the function in parts, i should break the integral from $A(\alpha)$ in intervals so i get

$$\begin{array}{ll}
A(\alpha)&=\int_{-\infty}^\frac{\pi}{2}f(x)\cos(\alpha x)dx+\int_\frac{\pi}{2}^\infty f(x)\cos(\alpha x)dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(x)\cos(\alpha x)dx+\int_\frac{\pi}{2}^\infty 0\cos(\alpha x)dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(x)\cos(\alpha x)dx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(x)\cos(\alpha x)-\alpha\cos(x)\sin(\alpha x)}{1-\alpha^2}\left|_{-\infty}^\frac{\pi}{2}\right.
\end{array}$$

Is this correct? i'm having trouble getting the right answer, following this, i get to

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{1-\alpha^2}d\alpha$$

which is quite different from what i needed, so i think i may be doing something wrong, any help would be aprreciated, thanks.

Comment: Since you know Fourier transforms, I suggest you to calculate the Fourier transform of the right-hand side and use the duality, i.e. the fact that the Fourier transform of a Fourier transform is the original function up to altering the sign of the argument.